# High school integration question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is from a past paper with no answer sheet.

Given that $ \int_{2}^{8} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \,dx  =6$, determine $ \int_{1}^{4} {f(\frac 8x)} \,dx$

let $u=\frac8x$,   $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{-8}{x^2}$

$ \int_{1}^{4} {f(\frac 8x)} \,dx = \int_{1}^{4} {f(u)} \, \frac{x^2 du}{-8}$

$ =\frac{-1}{8} \int_{1}^{4} {x^2f(u)} \,du$

Comment: Hint: U-substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t = \dfrac{8}{x}$ and use the fact that $\displaystyle \int\limits_a^b f(t)dt = \displaystyle \int\limits_a^b f(x)dx$.

Edited: From the begining, we have

$ \displaystyle\int\limits_2^8 \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}dx = 6 $

Then by the change of variable, we have

$ \displaystyle\int\limits_1^4 \dfrac{1}{8}f\left(\dfrac{8}{t} \right)dt = 6 $

Can you do it now?

Comment: I've edited it now using your suggestion. I thought i could get the $x^2$ to cancel out but I'm not sure.

Comment: @sargon129 i edited my comment

Comment: @sargon129 use $x=\dfrac8u$. You’ll get something very close to the integral whose value is given.

Comment: If you want to comment, please do it under the comments section of the question.

Comment: @LộcHuỳnhXuân did you just flip the limits around and cancel the -ve from the $\frac{-8}{x^2}$?

Comment: yes i am........

Comment: @LộcHuỳnhXuân Could you please complete the answer; I am curious.